# There is more space than I need in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using StackLayout and ListView to show some part of a view, but the ListView takes more space than I need, and leaves a blank space between the last row of the list and the profile continuation. It seems my ListView has more lines than the real list's length, or it has a fixed Height, I don't know... Here's my XAML:

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">

    <Label Text="{Binding Establishment.Name}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Style="{DynamicResource TitleStyle}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding Establishment.Category.Name,  StringFormat='Categoria: {0}'}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding Establishment.Description}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" XAlign="Start"/>

    <Label Text="Contatos" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Establishment.Contacts}" VerticalOptions="Start" HasUnevenRows="True">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextCell Text="{Binding Value}" Detail="{Binding StringType}" DetailColor="Gray"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

    <Label Text="Endereço" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  FontAttributes="Bold"/>

    <Label Text="{Binding Establishment.FullAddress}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"  />

    <Button Text="Ver no mapa"/>

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I fix it? I saw people using `HasUnevenRows="True"` but it didn't work to me.

Comment: have you tried setting a HeightRequest value on the ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys, but nothing worked for me. The solution that I thought by myself surely isn't the best one, but it works for me.....

At the XAML I left an empty StackLayout like this:

```
    <StackLayout x:Name="ContactsList" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10" Padding="8,0">
      <!-- Empty because it will be filled in code mode -->
    </StackLayout>
```

And then, in the .cs file, I called this method after InitializeComponent()  method:

```
    private void setUpContacts(Establishment establishment)
    {
        foreach(Contact contact in establishment.Contacts)
        {
            StackLayout row = new StackLayout
            {
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
            };

            row.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                TextColor = Color.Gray,
                Text = string.Format("{0}:", contact.StringType)
            });

            row.Children.Add(new Label
            {
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
                Text = contact.Value,
            });

            row.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer {
                Command = new Command(() => OnContactTapped(row, contact))
            });

            ContactsList.Children.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

I made this because the list isn't a really ListView, since I don't need scrolling functions directly in the list, it is just another part of the view. It won't cause any performance problem, I think, because it will have a small number of items (maximum 5). I'm marking this one as the correct answer to help others with this problem.

Please, if this is a solution that does not work for others, let me know and I'll find another way to do this.

Comment: If there are only going to be a few things in the list, I think your solution is just fine, especially if it works for you. I do some similar things with a `Grid` in different places in my code. Thanks for posting how you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

As **hvaughan3** said it's really not a good practice. But I had the same case and I used workaround with behavior:

```
public class ListViewHeightBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    private ListView _listView;

    public static readonly BindableProperty ExtraSpaceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ExtraSpace),
                                typeof(double),
                                typeof(ListViewHeightBehavior),
                                0d);

    public double ExtraSpace
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ExtraSpaceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExtraSpaceProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        _listView = bindable;
        _listView.PropertyChanged += (s, args) =>
        {
            var count = _listView.ItemsSource?.Count();
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(_listView.ItemsSource)
                    && count.HasValue
                    && count.Value > 0)
            {
                _listView.HeightRequest = _listView.RowHeight * count.Value + ExtraSpace;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
     <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
               HasUnevenRows="True">
      <ListView.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:ListViewHeightBehavior ExtraSpace="180"/>
      </ListView.Behaviors>
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
             // Your template
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: What do you think of my solution?

Comment: If there are only 5 items, so it's not a big deal I hope. But my behavior is working on my side, I think, you missed something in implementation.

Comment: Yes can be. When I debugged your solution it kind of worked for me, but I don't know why the RowHeight sometime came to me as -1 :/

Answer (score 2):

First, Xamarin suggests not putting a `ListView` in a `ScrollView`, since they both offer scrolling and fight with each other. I have personally tried this and it can often cause weird behavior, especially on Android.

Instead, what I do is use the `ListView.Header` with the  `ListView.HeaderTemplate` and the `ListView.Footer` with the  `ListView.FooterTemplate`. Xamarin link [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Headers_and_Footers) This allows for your exact scenario but without the weird behavior issues. If you would like to see an example of that, let me know.

If you must must must go with your current layout, you can try to check out [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/66248/#Comment_66248) post talking about how the `ListView` needs to be sized with specific `Height` and `Width` or with `LayoutOptions` since it is not supposed to fit the size of it's contents. There are a couple solutions in that post, none that I have tried yet.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24906102/3850012) post one of the workarounds that is given, says to add the the `ListView` to a `StackLayout` and add that to another `StackLayout`. Then set the inner `StackLayout`'s `VerticalOptions` to `LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand`.

So it might look like this:

```
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="10">

    ....

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Establishment.Contacts}" VerticalOptions="Start" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Value}" Detail="{Binding StringType}" DetailColor="Gray"/>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

    ....

  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you think of my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with Yehor Hromadskyi's solution.

- First off IEnumerable doesn't have a Count method. It must first be cast to an IEnumerable
- Second, if you don't set RowHeight you then the whole list collapses and you have the opposite problem.

Here are the changes to the code to fix those issues

```
public class ListViewHeightBehavior : Behavior<ListView>
{
    private ListView _listView;

    public static readonly BindableProperty ExtraSpaceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ExtraSpace),
                                typeof(double),
                                typeof(ListViewHeightBehavior),
                                0d);

    public static readonly BindableProperty DefaultRowHeightProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DefaultRowHeight),
                          typeof(int),
                          typeof(ListViewHeightBehavior),
                          40);

    public int DefaultRowHeight
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(DefaultRowHeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(DefaultRowHeightProperty, value);
    }
    public double ExtraSpace
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ExtraSpaceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ExtraSpaceProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(ListView bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);

        _listView = bindable;
        _listView.PropertyChanged += (s, args) =>
        {
            var count = _listView.ItemsSource?.Cast<object>()?.Count();
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(_listView.ItemsSource)
                    && count.HasValue
                    && count.Value > 0)
            {
                int rowHeight = _listView.RowHeight > 0 ? _listView.RowHeight : DefaultRowHeight;
                _listView.HeightRequest = rowHeight * count.Value + ExtraSpace;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sample layout shows that, you are using ListView inside the ScrollView and ListView have child in different height `(HasUnevenRows="True")`**

```
<ScrollView>
     <ListView HasUnevenRows="True">
     </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

This cause a blank space between the last row of the list and ScrollView.

> **Since you are already added scroll view as root. You can use**
>   **StackLayout `(BindableLayout)` for the same purpose.**

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout
        x:Name="DummyList"
        BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ContactList}"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell
                    Detail="{Binding StringType}"
                    DetailColor="Gray"
                    Text="{Binding Value}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```